# buttons conditioned by supported parameters

Tags: android, button, conditional-statements

I'd like to create a list of buttons that depend on device supported parameters ; for example, if the device's camera supports setting white balance and antibanding, then 2 corresponding buttons are displayed to allow the user to changes these settings; but if I run the same App on a device that supports only setting for white balance, then only one button is displayed.

I know how to create a list of buttons in the layout .xml file and I know how to test for supported parameters in the activity .java file, but I don't seem to find a way how to link these together.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

FWIW, here are the relevant pieces of my code so far

## activity .java file

```
package com.MyProject;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CameraSettingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraSettingActivity";
    private Object mCameraView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_setting);

        Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
        /* View mCameraView;*/
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Get supported white balance modes
        List<String> white_balance = params.getSupportedWhiteBalance();
        if (white_balance!=null) {
            String mString = white_balance.get(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA WHITE BALANCE : (" + mString + ")");
        }

        // Get supported antibanding modes
        List<String> antibanding = params.getSupportedAntibanding();
        if (antibanding!=null) {
            String mString = antibanding.get(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA ANTIBANDING : (" + mString + ")");
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.release();

    }
}
```

## layout .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/green_background"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/under_construction"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/white_balance_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/white_balance"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/antibanding_button"
        android:layout_width="100dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/antibanding"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just grab the Button instance using findViewById and make it VISIBLE/GONE according the available features.

```
if (white_balance!=null) {
 String mString = white_balance.get(0);
 Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA WHITE BALANCE : (" + mString + ")");
} else {
  Button whiteBalance = (Button)findViewById(R.id. white_balance_button);
  whiteBalance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} //same for anibanding
```